# How does Apache know which file to use in /etc/httpd/conf.d?

Tags: linux, apache, centos

I installed https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/tree/master/install/centos.

One of the steps was to delete `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` (actually rename to ssl.conf.bak), and add a new `gitlab.conf` file.

How does Apache know which file to use in /etc/httpd/conf.d?  I would have thought that I would have had to edit `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, and specify the file, but this does not appear to be the case.  Does Apache just use any file with a `.conf` extension located in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`?  If so, would an error occur if there was more than one?

Comment: It typically just includes `conf.d/*.conf` via a line in the main config.  Depends on how the OS/distro sets things up, though.  It's entirely possible to not have a `conf.d` directory at all.

Comment: @cHoa.  Yes, I have that line in my httpd.conf file.  So if I had more than one, it would just include all of them I suppose.  Thanks

Comment: @cHao.  Feel free to post your comment as an answer, and I will select it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It depends on how the server is configured.  But it's common to have a line similar to this:

```
Include conf.d/*.conf
```

in the main config (or some other config file included by it).  That will include all the `.conf` files in the `conf.d` directory.

Other groups of files could be set up the same way, by simply adding a similar line(with a different directory name, of course).  Ubuntu, for example, has a directory named `sites-enabled` that contains files to set up the sites active on the server.